# Hadoop: passing data between consecutive mapreduce tasks

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have chained mapreduce jobs in the following way:
map1 -> reduce1 -> map2 -> reduce2
During map1 step as a side effect I calculate data that will be needed only during reduce2 step, so I don't want to pass it all the way through the chain. What is the best way to pass this data so that on reduce2 step I could get data from both map2 and map1?

Thanks

Comment: you don't want reduce1 at all? or is it at few cases you will need the data to pass through reduce1 and reduce2?

Comment: No, I need output of reduce1 - it will be passed to map2. My point is that part of map1 output is not needed for reduce1, but needed for reduce2, so I don't want this part of data to be passed through the whole chain.

Comment: Basically, during map1 I calculate A and B, where A is to be passed to reduce1 and processed there, while B is to be passed to reduce2 that will process it together with output of map2.

Comment: I cannot think of anything else that is shared except for the HDFS. That is, you can write a file in the Hadoop file system during map1 and read it back during reduce2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you output *A* and *B* from mapper 1. Then, you want *A* to go to reducer 1 and *B* to go to reducer 2, along with the output of mapper 2.
The best option I can see is the following:

**JOB 1:** 
To differentiate *A* from *B*, use `MultipleOutputs` in the first job... Use a common prefix (e.g. in the values) for the type *B* intermediate output of mapper 1 that will distinguish them from type *A* output. In reducer 1, when you see the prefix, remove it and write the *B* s in the *B* output path.

**JOB 2:** 
Use `MultipleInputs` in your second job. Use mapper 2 for the input that it processes and an IdentityMapper for *B*. This will simply forward *B* to reducer 2, where you will also process the output of mapper 2.

A simple code snippet:

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/input/path/of/job/2"), SequenceFileInputFormat.class, Mapper2.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/path/of/B"), SequenceFileInputFormat.class, IdentityMapper.class);

conf.setReducerClass(Reducer2.class);
```

where `MultipleInputs` is `import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleInputs;`.

You cannot get data in reducer 2 and process them the same way that you process the output of mapper 2, unless you use a mapper for them, too. Generally, you cannot use a reducer without a mapper. The closest to that is to use an IdentityMapper.

If you want to process *B* in another way, then, you can get them through the Distributed Cache, or if it is a single numer or two, just set a variable with this value, using `conf.set("variableName", variableValue);`. Then, you can get this value in the `setup()` method of reducer 2, using `conf.get("variableName", defaultValue);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a comprehensive reply! I thought about using MultipleOutputs, but never took into consideration MultipleInputs.